# Knockout From and To datepicker scenario

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a scenario where I use datetimepicker for inputting From and To dates. If I put a constraint in such a way that the "To" dates cannot be lesser than the "From" date, the bindings do not work anymore. Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ericpanorel/PkpP6/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datepicker will not fire change event in case you supplied onselect. Below is the piece from jquery ui code:

```
var onSelect = this._get(inst, 'onSelect');
if (onSelect)
  onSelect.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null), [dateStr, inst]);  // trigger custom callback
else if (inst.input)
   inst.input.trigger('change'); // fire the change event
```

To solve you problem, update model in both onSelect (this will fire when user selected date from datepicker window) and 'onchange' (last one you still need to handle textbox editing

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PkpP6/1/

Comment: Thanks! I also found a work around using knockout's subscribe feature. This is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ericpanorel/PkpP6/4/

Comment: for subscription I would better move this to bindingHandler - http://jsfiddle.net/PkpP6/6/